# How can I find a proportional length on a perpendicular line from a perspective?

Tags: projective-geometry

I am working on a project where I am mapping images of buildings onto 3D meshes and I want the dimensions of the mesh to be proportional to the building in the image.

I have six points for a given image that describe two sets of vanishing lines and a vertical line where they intersect.  I want to know the length of one side of the building proportional to the other. I can assume that the lines intersect at a right angle and that the vertical lines are the same height in real space.

Referring to the linked image, is there a way I can find the length of *a* given an assumed length for *b*?

[image]

Comment: Two views should be given maybe ?

Comment: @Narasimham the goal of the project is to generate models from single-view historical photographs, so unfortunately that is not an option. The whole process would ideally be done with no more information than a single photograph.